# Flutter: Dismissing a dialog by swiping

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created this image viewer using dialog and I need to implement swipe to exist (dragging top or down) to perform `Navigator.of(context).pop()`

Here is my code that I need to implement swipe within it.

```
showGeneralDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierColor: Colors.grey.shade900
      .withOpacity(0.95), // Background color
  barrierDismissible: false,
  barrierLabel: 'Dialog',
  transitionDuration: Duration(
      milliseconds:
          400), 
  pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
    // Makes widget fullscreen
    return SafeArea(
      child: SizedBox.expand(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
          
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

[image]

Comment: does BottomSheet work?

Comment: I haven't tried yet, what is the difference between them. Does ButtomSheet implement drag or swipe actions?

Comment: Yes, https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap the `SafeArea` inside the dialog with a `GestureDetector` and use its `onVerticalDragUpdate`.

I also wrapped the `Column` with a transparent `Container` to make the `GestureDetector` work.

```
showGeneralDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierColor: Colors.grey.shade900
  .withOpacity(0.95), // Background color
  barrierDismissible: false,
  barrierLabel: 'Dialog',
  transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
  pageBuilder: (context, __, ___) {
    // Makes widget fullscreen
    return GestureDetector(
      onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
        int sensitivity = 10;
        if (details.delta.dy > sensitivity ||
            details.delta.dy < -sensitivity) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        }
      },
      child: SafeArea(
        child: SizedBox.expand(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: Column(
              children: [],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

To implement the swipe to dismiss behavior, you can use a `Dismissible` instead of the `GestureDetector`:

```
showGeneralDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierColor: Colors.grey.shade900
  .withOpacity(0.95), // Background color
  barrierDismissible: false,
  barrierLabel: 'Dialog',
  transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
  pageBuilder: (context, __, ___) {
    // Makes widget fullscreen
    return Dismissible(
      direction: DismissDirection.vertical,
      onDismissed: (_) {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
      key: Key("key"),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: SizedBox.expand(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  height: 300,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: That works fine, thanks a lot. In addition to that, I need that scroll behavior when you drag. is there any way to implement it to be a full solution for me.

Comment: By scrolling, do you mean the dialog should be closed with a scrolling animation? If not, can you elaborate more? @AliAbbas

Comment: what I need is the content inside the dialog as shown in the image above, when it get swiped top or down that swipe triggers an action to exit the dialog.
For the end user, he just need to swipe the image or any part inside the dialog to exist just like image viewer in facebook or twitter.
Your answer did the job but without any scroll of content.

Comment: I added the swipe to dismiss behavior. Check it out. @AliAbbas

Comment: That exactly what I want, great job.